# Using sql:column function in xpath in values method

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery-sql

I have two tables:

- One called @settings with xml values
- Another called @nodesToFind with a list of nodes to extract from the xml values in the first table

I want to get a list of the values for each NodePath for each RowId.

This query uses the `sql:column` function in the xpath of the values method on the Settings column but it returns the NodePath itself instead of the value:

```
declare @settings table (RowId int identity, Settings xml)
insert @settings (Settings) values ('<settings><Settings1><Settings1a><Setting1a1>1-1a1</Setting1a1></Settings1a><Setting1b>1-1b</Setting1b><Setting1c>1-1c</Setting1c></Settings1><Settings2><Setting2a>1-2a</Setting2a></Settings2></settings>')
insert @settings (Settings) values ('<settings><Settings1><Settings1a><Setting1a1>2-1a1</Setting1a1></Settings1a><Setting1b>2-1b</Setting1b><Setting1c>2-1c</Setting1c></Settings1><Settings2><Setting2a>2-2a</Setting2a></Settings2></settings>')
insert @settings (Settings) values ('<settings><Settings1><Settings1a><Setting1a1>3-1a1</Setting1a1></Settings1a><Setting1b>3-1b</Setting1b><Setting1c>3-1c</Setting1c></Settings1><Settings2><Setting2a>3-2a</Setting2a></Settings2></settings>')

declare @nodesToFind table (NodePath varchar(max))
insert @nodesToFind (NodePath) values ('/Settings/Settings1/Settings1a/Setting1a1')
insert @nodesToFind (NodePath) values ('/Settings/Settings1/Setting1b')
insert @nodesToFind (NodePath) values ('/Settings/Settings1/Setting1c')
insert @nodesToFind (NodePath) values ('/Settings/Settings2/Setting2a')

select
    S.RowId, 
    NTF.NodePath,
    S.Settings.value('(sql:column("NodePath"))[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from @settings S
cross apply @nodesToFind NTF
```

The result is this:

```
RowId  NodePath                                   Value
-----  -----------------------------------------  -----------------------------------------
1      /Settings/Settings1/Settings1a/Setting1a1  /Settings/Settings1/Settings1a/Setting1a1
2      /Settings/Settings1/Settings1a/Setting1a1  /Settings/Settings1/Settings1a/Setting1a1
3      /Settings/Settings1/Settings1a/Setting1a1  /Settings/Settings1/Settings1a/Setting1a1
1      /Settings/Settings1/Setting1b              /Settings/Settings1/Setting1b
2      /Settings/Settings1/Setting1b              /Settings/Settings1/Setting1b
3      /Settings/Settings1/Setting1b              /Settings/Settings1/Setting1b
1      /Settings/Settings1/Setting1c              /Settings/Settings1/Setting1c
2      /Settings/Settings1/Setting1c              /Settings/Settings1/Setting1c
3      /Settings/Settings1/Setting1c              /Settings/Settings1/Setting1c
1      /Settings/Settings2/Setting2a              /Settings/Settings2/Setting2a
2      /Settings/Settings2/Setting2a              /Settings/Settings2/Setting2a
3      /Settings/Settings2/Setting2a              /Settings/Settings2/Setting2a
```

What is wrong with the `S.Settings.value('(sql:column("NodePath"))[1]', 'varchar(max)')` line?

Comment: You can't use a completely dynamic node path with a `/` in it. The only thing you can do is use single-level predicates like `S.Settings.value('(*[local-name() = sql:column("NodePath1")] / *[local-name() = sql:column("NodePath2")]/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')`

Comment: @Charlieface, that limitation is disappointing, thank you.

Comment: Does a series of predicates (as above) work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XQuery you are trying to use is effectively being run dynaimcally. Unfortunately, you cannot use dynamic XQuery in SQL Server. Each XQuery *must* be static.

What you could do in your specific situation, is to break up each node predicate into separate columns. Then in the XQuery you can descend to the relevant node by checking each column. For example:

```sql
declare @settings table (RowId int identity, Settings xml)
insert @settings (Settings) values ('<settings><Settings1><Settings1a><Setting1a1>1-1a1</Setting1a1></Settings1a><Setting1b>1-1b</Setting1b><Setting1c>1-1c</Setting1c></Settings1><Settings2><Setting2a>1-2a</Setting2a></Settings2></settings>')
insert @settings (Settings) values ('<settings><Settings1><Settings1a><Setting1a1>2-1a1</Setting1a1></Settings1a><Setting1b>2-1b</Setting1b><Setting1c>2-1c</Setting1c></Settings1><Settings2><Setting2a>2-2a</Setting2a></Settings2></settings>')
insert @settings (Settings) values ('<settings><Settings1><Settings1a><Setting1a1>3-1a1</Setting1a1></Settings1a><Setting1b>3-1b</Setting1b><Setting1c>3-1c</Setting1c></Settings1><Settings2><Setting2a>3-2a</Setting2a></Settings2></settings>')

declare @nodesToFind table (NodePath1 nvarchar(max), NodePath2 nvarchar(max), NodePath3 nvarchar(max), NodePath4 nvarchar(max))
insert @nodesToFind (NodePath1, NodePath2, NodePath3, NodePath4) values ('settings','Settings1','Settings1a','Setting1a1')
insert @nodesToFind (NodePath1, NodePath2, NodePath3, NodePath4) values ('settings','Settings1','Setting1b',null)
insert @nodesToFind (NodePath1, NodePath2, NodePath3, NodePath4) values ('settings','Settings1','Setting1c',null)
insert @nodesToFind (NodePath1, NodePath2, NodePath3, NodePath4) values ('settings','Settings2','Setting2a',null)

select
    S.RowId, 
    NTF.*,
    S.Settings.value('((
        for $i1 in *[local-name() = sql:column("NodePath1")]
        return 
            if (empty(sql:column("NodePath2")))
            then $i1
            else for $i2 in ($i1/*[local-name() = sql:column("NodePath2")])
                 return
                     if (empty(sql:column("NodePath3")))
                     then $i2
                     else for $i3 in $i2/*[local-name() = sql:column("NodePath3")]
                          return
                              if (empty(sql:column("NodePath4")))
                              then $i3
                              else $i3/*[local-name() = sql:column("NodePath4")]
    )/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from @settings S
cross join @nodesToFind NTF
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=071c12c91f686221d6c6dbcbd0f58005)

As you can see, it is made significantly more complex (and probably slow) by the fact that there are multiple possible node levels. If you can restrict it to only one level of node then you can remove the `if` `else` sections.

Comment: Although the settings can have multiple node levels (possibly more than 4), this is useful. Thank you very much.  I am still learning xpath and xquery.